# angular how to display return key in json

Tags: angular

In my json I have field with enter key in it..
when I print in my ui, lines are not coming in next line.
In my below json 'Note-Detail' I was mentioning.

```
Note-Detail:"Technology: N/A ↵Problem Code: N/A ↵ Product: NA ↵ Product Family: CTSMPS ↵ Software Version: N/A ↵ Problem Details: Banding issue"
NoteId:816214256
Status:"External"
Time:"2016-08-11 20:57:05.0"
Type:"Customer Symptom"
User:"ANSANCHO"
```

Comment: How do you print it? Can you add some code of yours?

Answer (score 0):

try replace you enter on "\n"

```
replace("↵","\n");
```

but ↵ not correct